# How to track down "incorrect checksum for freed object"

Tags: ios, debugging, crash, malloc

I have spent quite some time trying to trace this problem and read multiple suggestion from others with the same problem. I deal with a large code base so finding the problem without some hints is like looking for a needle in a hay stack.

On of the suggestion I read is to add a break point on *malloc_error_break* - but how do I do that. I understand that I have to add a symbolic break point but I'm not sure what exactly to enter in the two text fields, Symbol and Module?

I tried to enable Malloc Scribble and Malloc Guard Edges - but none of it results in any break point or crashes.

If I enable Zombie Objects the programs stops crashing but there is nothing in the output log showing any problems.

Finally I tried to enable Guard Malloc. I understand that it only works with the simulator so I tries that - but the problem is that the programs crashes in the start up phase before   any line in my program is executed:

```
0x958e0cd4  <+0000>  mov    0x4(%esp),%eax
0x958e0cd8  <+0004>  mov    %gs:0x0(,%eax,4),%eax   < Crash
0x958e0ce0  <+0012>  ret
```

and the call stack looks like this:

```
pthread_getspecific
__dyld__dyld_start
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: symbol= `malloc_error_break` module need not be defined in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

To add a breakpoint on malloc_error_break, simply stop in the debugger and type `b malloc_error_break` at the "gdb" or "lldb" prompt.

Comment: If I stop the debugger and type b in the "gdb" it just seems to set a break point at the execution pointer.